# Macro for generating immediates for AVX shuffle intrinsics

Tags: c, macros, intel, intrinsics, avx

In AVX, is there any special macro that helps to construct the immediate constant for `_mm256_shuffle_*` intrinsics, like `_MM_SHUFFLE(..)` for its SSE counterpart? I can't find any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still use `_MM_SHUFFLE()` for shuffles that take the control input as an 8bit immediate.  e.g. `_mm256_shuffle_epi32` ([`vpshufd`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFD.html)) does the same shuffle on both lanes.

`_MM_SHUFFLE(dd,cc,bb,aa)` just packs the low 2 bits of each arg into a `0bddccbbaa`.

You can write `_MM_SHUFFLE(1,1,1,1)` (broadcast element 1) as `0b01010101`, i.e. `0x55`.

You can use C++14 separators (or whatever they're called) to write it as `0b01'01'01'01` for better human-readability, esp. in cases where each element is different.

Comment: I think base-4 is better in this case than binary. Two base-4 digits is one base-16 (hex) digit. For example if you want to shuffle 3,1,1,2 that would be 3*4+1, 1*4+2 = 0xda. On the other hand _MM_SHUFFLE is basically base-4 and more readable.

Comment: @Zboson: can you use base-4 in C?  I use _MM_SHUFFLE in C, but `0baabbccdd` in asm.  I guess in a `.S` file that gcc will run through CPP before assembling, you could copy the a macro definition for _MM_SHUFFLE.

Comment: No, I do it in my head and write out the hex value or I write a comment. But `_MM_SHUFFLE` basically is a base-4 macro.